# How is the impact force on the landing gear distributed in fighters?

Tags: fighter, landing-gear, aircraft-physics, weight

1. Upon landing, what percentage of weight is distributed on the main and the nose landing gears of fighters?
2. Upon landing of a fighter aircraft, what would be the approximate time of transfer of the impact force on the landing gear?

Comment: Upon landing, the time to transfer impact force to the landing gear is “upon landing”, or effectively zero.  What makes you think there is a delay, or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: -1 because you spend zero effort on the title

Answer (score 3):

Depends (as usual...)

On normal landings all the force is taken by the main gear - the nose gear is still in the air. Later on it only takes a small force compared to the impact of touchdown.

But: not knowing what aircraft and what kind of landing (normal controlled on land vs. the "crash" of carrier landings), the answer would not be able to be more specific.